# How can I decompile many jars at once?

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

Well, I guess subject says it all :)

The ideal solution would find all jars within a certain folder (they might be in sub-folders), and write all the sources found into a single "src" directory, of course maintaing the package folders.

Concrete use case: decompile all Eclipse plugin jars

Comment: You should require decompiler s/w. Google for best available.

Comment: Can you use the 'find' command?

Comment: If you just wanna see code when required then you can also use Eclipse's decompiler plugin.

Comment: @Harry Joy - didn't know that eclipse ships with a decompiler plugin ... I know, there's a plugin for the [java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) but that's "3rd party".

Comment: @Andreas_D - yes there are decompile plugins for eclipse. see this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/ and http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-decompiler-plugin-for-eclipse/ and http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/22657

Comment: @Harry, I know, there are some, but none of them qualifies for the term "Eclipse's decompiler plugin". They're all 3rd party but you can't get them with eclipse distributions or through the official eclipse pages.

Comment: @Andreas_D - yes you are right but at least you can have them in eclipse to look through class files by decompiling them.

Comment: .jar files are .zip files..  You can unzip them all into the same folder and then decompile that folder tree.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Download [JAD Decompiler](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad).

- Unjar all your jar files (using the command `jar xvf`) to some directory. Let's call this `${unjar.dir}`.
- Create a directory for JAD to write out the decompiled sources. Let's call this `${target.dir}`.
- Execute the following command:

```
    jad -o -r -sjava -d${target.dir} ${unjar.dir}/**/*.class
```

options are:

```
-o       - overwrite output files without confirmation
-r       - restore package directory structure
-s <ext> - output file extension (default: .jad)
```

Comment: are you sure, JAD can decompile code for Java 1.5 and above? I think there was a certain .. limitation and the project looks dead...

Comment: Okay, I am on my way. First hurdle: How to unjar many jars on a Windows command prompt? Solution found: for /f %f in ('dir /b ..\*.jar') do jar xf ..\%f

Comment: thanku dogbane,   this is the simplest solution ever for decomipling the entire jar

Comment: one param that helped me was `-lradix<num>- display long integers using the specified radix` (in my case for serialVersionUID fields), default is 16  it seems...

Answer (score 1):

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Comment: In my experience, jd produces better decompiled code than jad, and more reliably. It makes no attempt to get line numbers right, though, which is a pain. However, I don't know of any way to automate it - if you have a lot of jars, you have to decompile each one by hand.

Comment: -1 This does not answer my question of decompiling multiple jars at once

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you need to decompile all classes in a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Decompile eclipse plugins??

Apart from the existence of a technical solution - (1) you can get all source files for the (official) eclipse plugins as bundles and (2) don't expect that the decompiler results will compile or can be used to debug the code.

So if you want to study the source of eclipse and it's plugins, decompiling is .. say .. not the *best* idea.

Comment: I know... I've got my reasons ;)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool names `code-collection` using `shell script` and `cfr` to `find` and `decompile` all `jar`, `war` files at once.

After decompiling jar, war files, you could use my tool to find and copy all specific files (`.js`, `.html` for example) to a new directory.

[image]

Visit my project at: [code-collection](https://github.com/thoqbk/code-collection)

Comment: Can I ask you to review [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)? You may find it helpful when posting about OSS projects in answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows equivalent command for this would be:

```
jad -o -r -sjava -d "target.dir" "unjar.dir/**/*.class"
```